# Codec can't decode byte - base64-decoding

Tags: python, base64

I'm having some trouble decoding base64 text, using `base64.b64decode()`. I have a function:

```
import base64

def base64_to_bin(base):
    decoded = ''
    for letter in base64.b64decode(base):
        decoded += bin(letter)[2:].zfill(8)
        
    return decoded
```

If I do `base64_to_bin('YQ==')` I get `01100001`.  If I do `base64_to_bin('fXBz')` I get `011111010111000001110011`. But, if I move the `f`, `X`, or `B` up (or should it be down?) by one letter, I get this:

```
for letter in base64.b64decode(base).decode():
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Why does changing one letter break it?

Comment: What did you expect `.decode()` to do?

Comment: @mkrieger1 If I take it out I get this error:`ord() expected string of length 1, but int found`

Comment: What are you using `ord` for?

Comment: @mkrieger1 good point...

Comment: Or rather, what are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm trying to convert a base64 into binary.

Comment: @mkrieger1 If you do just `b64decode()` you get the base64 in ascii.

Comment: Now that you changed the code in the question, what remains the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry for not responding, the internet went out. Anyway, taking out the `ord()` and `.decode()` fixed it for some reason... ty for the help